# Ethernet not detected in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, networking, ethernet, lan, wired

I am a new to Linux. I cannot get a LAN connection in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. It used to work in Windows 7.

Here is the result from `if config -a`

```
enp0s25   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f0:de:f1:2c:0c:ce  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f8500000-f8520000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:93790 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:93790 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:8114335 (8.1 MB)  TX bytes:8114335 (8.1 MB)

wlp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:24:d7:69:9f:28  
          inet addr:192.168.0.9  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2606:a000:4dc4:e300:9058:8ec2:f59e:27d8/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::6476:3f7c:2c08:839a/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2606:a000:4dc4:e300:72bc:fcf9:87c9:a0b1/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:225018 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:118451 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:86856712 (86.8 MB)  TX bytes:17154818 (17.1 MB)
```

Here is the output from `lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor PCI Express x16 Root Port (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 06)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 06)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev 06)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev 06)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a6)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QM57 Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218M [NVS 3100M] (rev a2)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 (rev 35)
0d:00.0 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd MMC/SD Host Controller (rev 01)
0d:00.1 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd R5U2xx (R5U230 / R5U231 / R5U241) [Memory Stick Host Controller] (rev 01)
0d:00.3 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 PCIe IEEE 1394 Controller (rev 01)
ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 02)
ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 02)
ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 02)
ff:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved (rev 02)
ff:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved (rev 02)
```

And here is the output from `sudo lshw -C network`

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: enp0s25
       version: 06
       serial: f0:de:f1:2c:0c:ce
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.12-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:25 memory:f8500000-f851ffff memory:f8525000-f8525fff ioport:1820(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Ultimate-N 6300
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 35
       serial: 00:24:d7:69:9f:28
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.10.0-32-generic firmware=9.221.4.1 build 25532 ip=192.168.0.9 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:30 memory:f8100000-f8101fff
```

I don't really know how to interpret those results in terms of troubleshooting, but I would appreciate any help that you could provide.

**Update**

I am sorry for the poor explanation. Ubuntu is not detecting the the fact that it is connected (i.e., it says "Wire Unplugged"). The ethernet port lights are off.

Here is the output from  `dmesg | grep -e e100 -e enp`

```
 dmesg | grep -e e100 -e enp
[    1.253294] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.2.6-k
[    1.253294] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[    1.253459] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[    1.411004] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) f0:de:f1:2c:0c:ce
[    1.411007] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    1.411083] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: MAC: 9, PHY: 10, PBA No: A002FF-0FF
[    1.411697] e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: renamed from eth0
[   20.756979] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s25: link is not ready
[   20.954637] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s25: link is not ready
```

Comment: I assume your question is actually that it isn't connected, since it is obviously *detected*. Are there any clues in the log? Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `dmesg | grep -e e100 -e enp`  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the post. The actually issue is that the network connection is not detected (i.e., Network setting say "Cable unplugged").

Comment: Please try another known good cable. Also, at the Network Manager icon, disconnect the wireless and try to connect the ethernet. Then run: `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -e enp -e etwork | tail -n 25 > ask.txt` Reconnect the wireless. Find the document *ask.txt* in your /home/user (Jim??) directory and paste it here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com  So far, we see nothing wrong in your posted details.

Comment: I don't think it's the cable, because I just connected my Windows 10 laptop to the same connection without problems.

Comment: I did try a new cable, and it worked with the Windows 10 laptop, but not the Ubuntu laptop. When I disconnect from the WiFi, it just says the ethernet "cable unplugged.". 

http://paste.ubuntu.com/25312820/

Comment: Is your ethernet cable going to a switch or hub, or directly into a router or modem?

Comment: It's plugged into a Netgear Powerline adapter. The Power LED and Powerline LED are both green. The Ethernet LED is off, but turns on when the cable is plugged into my Windows 10 laptop. It connects fine with the Windows 10 laptop. 

As a side note, my whole Network Manager appears to be having problems. It doesn't refresh the WiFi list. It won't let me connect to other WiFi networks (i.e., clicking the Connect button doesn't do anything). It says my household WiFi networks are out of range, etc.

Answer (score 3):

It is detected. It's enp0s25. You just don't have an IP address. Look in Settings -> Network -> Wired and turn on dhcp